# How to map/filter data correctly with luxon (DateTimeNow) and ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, date, filter, luxon

I would like to explain my problem of the day.

I have a array which looks like this

```
[{status: "closed",createdAt: "2022-01-13T15:28:25.239Z"},{status: "closed",createdAt: "2022-01-10T15:28:25.239Z"},{status: "open",createdAt: "2021-11-25T15:28:25.239Z"}]
```

I filter to retrieve only the data with the status "closed"

```
const countData = data?.filter(
    (item) => item.status === "closed"
);
const count = countData?.length;
```

this works well, it correctly returns the number to me.

I would like to add a new filter with Luxon.

I would like to take the date of today with luxon, and, as a result, display the objects that correspond to this date

```
const dateNow = DateTime.now().toISO();
console.log(dateNow) 
2022-01-13T16:23:44.873+01:00
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check if a given Luxon DateTime object represent the same day of today, you can use [`hasSame`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimehassame) passing `date` as second parameter

> Return whether this DateTime is in the same unit of time as another DateTime. Higher-order units must also be identical for this function to return `true`. Note that time zones are **ignored** in this comparison, which compares the **local** calendar time. Use [DateTime#setZone](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimesetzone) to convert one of the dates if needed.

In your case, you can have something like the following code:

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;
const input = [{
  status: "closed",
  createdAt: "2022-01-13T15:28:25.239Z"
}, {
  status: "closed",
  createdAt: "2022-01-10T15:28:25.239Z"
}, {
  status: "open",
  createdAt: "2021-11-25T15:28:25.239Z"
}, {
  status: "closed",
  createdAt: new Date().toISOString()
}];

const todayItems = input.filter(item => {
  return DateTime.fromISO(item.createdAt).hasSame(DateTime.now(), 'day') && item.status == "closed";
});
console.log(todayItems)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@2.3.0/build/global/luxon.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Vincezoc very nice, it works too, could you modify it and show me if I also wanted to return with the "status": "closed", to ?

Comment: @Neff if you want to filter items also by status, you can simply add the condition in the filter function, as shown in the updated answer

Comment: Sorry to bother you in here,


I don't get it why, it gave me false

`const day =
  "Thu Feb 10 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)";

const TODAY = new Date();

const test = DateTime.fromISO(day).startOf("day").equals(TODAY);

console.log(test)`

Comment: @Krisna multiple issue, first of all `day` is not in ISO 8601 format, so `DateTime.fromISO(day).isValid` is `false`, then [`equals`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimeequals) _check Two DateTimes are equal iff they represent the same millisecond_ that is unlikely your case. Please note that you should not ask new questions in comments, ask a new question if needed following [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide, reading docs may help you to clarify your doubts.

Answer (score 2):

Luxon has a function that let's you get a date at certain point of a parameter that's called `startOf`. So you can do something like:

```
const todayDate = DateTime.now().startOf("day");
```

So your `todayDate` variable will be your current date, but at 00:00:00 time.

And you can make the transformation of the elements date during your filter function to compare them to `todayDate` like this:

```
//Please consider that the example for today was at 2022-01-13
const array = [
  { 
    name: "this is for today", 
    date: "2022-01-13T15:28:25.239Z" 
  }, 
  { 
    name: "this was for yesterday", 
    date: "2022-01-12T15:28:25.239Z" 
  }];

const todayDate = DateTime.now().startOf("day");

const todayElements = array.filter((element) => {
  return DateTime.fromISO(element.date).startOf("day").equals(todayDate);
});
```

Comment: It's possible to use `.hasSame(DateTime.local(), "day");`

Comment: @MaCadiz it works really well

Comment: @lazy.lizard you are right. That's an even better approach. Thanks